# Force change array key to continous numbering

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a problem like the example below.
The array output that I have is array key #4 is missing,

```
Array (    [0] => Array
      (
           [milestonename] => Start Date
           [datefrom] => 03/01/2015
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => Finish Date
           [datefrom] => 03/24/2015
       )

   [2] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => Release Date
           [datefrom] => 03/29/2015
       )

   [3] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => release dasa
           [datefrom] => 03/16/2015
       )

   [5] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => dasawarsa
           [datefrom] => 03/16/2015
       )

   [6] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => lasawara
           [datefrom] => 03/18/2015
       )

   [7] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => testing das
           [datefrom] => 03/29/2015
       ) )
```

I want this array key to be continuous numbering like array key is keep sorting by number

```
Array (    [0] => Array
      (
           [milestonename] => Start Date
           [datefrom] => 03/01/2015
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => Finish Date
           [datefrom] => 03/24/2015
       )

   [2] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => Release Date
           [datefrom] => 03/29/2015
       )

   [3] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => release dasa
           [datefrom] => 03/16/2015
       )

   [4] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => dasawarsa
           [datefrom] => 03/16/2015
       )

   [5] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => lasawara
           [datefrom] => 03/18/2015
       )

   [6] => Array
       (
           [milestonename] => testing das
           [datefrom] => 03/29/2015
       ) )
```

Comment: Hi, could you show us any code in order to troubleshoot this issue further?

Comment: If it's absolutely essential that keys are consecutive, then simply do `$myArray = array_values($myArray);` otherwise why worry about it? Generally, it shouldn't be essential

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$fixed_array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: Thanks i have tried it and works :)

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `array_values` function

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```